# can anyone tell me why pagination doesn't work

Tags: django

How do I use pagination with Django? this code is using Django
and this is the code
I try a lot of ways to do it but it doesn't work
this website is a blog website
please help me with How can I do that?

home.html

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul id='pagination' class="pagination justify-content-end container-fluid">

    <li id='hasPrevious' class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li id='hasNext' class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    context = {"blogs" : BlogModel.objects.all()}
    context["services"] = Service.objects.all()
    context["works"] = RecentWork.objects.all()
    return render(request,"home.html", context)



def blogs_pagination(request,page_number=1):
    blogs_query = BlogModel.objects.all().order_by("-created_at")
    blogs_query = Paginator(blogs_query, 3)
    blogs = blogs_query.page(page_number)
    current_page_pagination = blogs_query.page(page_number)

    has_next = current_page_pagination.has_next()

    has_previous = current_page_pagination.has_previous()

    total_pages = blogs_query.num_pages
    return JsonResponse(
        {
            "blogs": [blogs.serialize() for blog in blogs],
            "totalPages": total_pages,
            "hasNext": has_next,
            "hasPrevious": has_previous,
        },safe=False
    )
```

Comment: this article  maybe help you https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html

Comment: Can you share the url pattern of your `blogs_pagination` and how you fetch the items?